# Deduced return type cannot be used before it is defined

Tags: c++, c++17, template-meta-programming

I have produced a minimal example which reproduces the same compiler error as my application:

My minimal `.hpp` file :

```
#include <type_traits>

template< typename CT1, typename CT2 >
inline decltype(auto)
operator+( const baseContainer<CT1>&, const baseContainer<CT2>& );


template<typename CT>
class baseContainer
{
    public:

    constexpr CT& operator*() noexcept;
    constexpr const CT& operator*() const noexcept;
};
// non const version
template< typename CT >
constexpr CT& baseContainer<CT>::operator*() noexcept
{
    return static_cast<CT&>( *this );
}

// const version
template< typename CT >
 constexpr const CT& baseContainer<CT>::operator*() const noexcept
{
    return static_cast<const CT&>( *this );
}

template< typename T >
class container :
    public baseContainer<container<T>>

{
    public:
    using result_type = container<T>;
    T* v_;
};


template<class CT1, class CT2>
class ExprAdd :
    public baseContainer<ExprAdd<CT1,CT2> >
{
    public:
    using result_type_1   = typename CT1::result_type;
    using result_type_2   = typename CT2::result_type;

    using result_type = std::remove_cv_t< std::remove_reference_t< decltype(std::declval<result_type_1>() + std::declval<result_type_2>() )> >;

    ExprAdd( const CT1& lhs , const CT2& rhs )noexcept
        : lhs_(lhs), rhs_(rhs)
        {};

    private:
    CT1& lhs_;
    CT2& rhs_;

};


template< typename CT1, typename CT2 >
inline decltype(auto)
operator+( const baseContainer<CT1>& lhs, const baseContainer<CT2>& rhs )
{
    using returntype = const ExprAdd<CT1,CT2>;
    return returntype(*lhs, *rhs);
}
```

And the main file:

```
#include "addTrait.hpp"
using cont = container<float>;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    using test_type = std::remove_cv_t< std::remove_reference_t< decltype(std::declval<cont>() + std::declval<cont>() )> >;
    // cont A,B,C;
    // A = B+C;
    return 0;
}
```

This code generates an error saying

> error: function 'operator+<container, container>' with deduced return type cannot be used before it is defined
> using result_type = std::remove_cv_t< std::remove_reference_t< decltype(std::declval<result_type_1>() + std::declval<result_type_2>() )> >;

Although, I am forward declaring the `operator+`. I am not sure how to fix this problem.

In the main, I am just testing whether the `result_type` would work in the class `ExprAdd`. When doing `A=B+C` the same error error message appears.

I have tested with `clang` and `g++-10` using `std=c++17`

**UPDATE**

After I tried the suggestion in the comment to directly specify the return type I realised a problem with that. The return type should in fact be `baseContainer`. For example, doing a simple operation like `A+B` the return type should become a `baseContainer` just like `A` and `B`.

Comment: Forwarding functions which return `auto`/`decltype(auto)` doesn't allow to know their return type (to be used for deduction for example)...

Comment: Okay thanks , what possibilities are there to resolve this issue. Because the `operator+` return type should be determined at the time of instantiation. For this example, there is only one way but not in reality.

Comment: Specify the return type of `operator+()` as `ExprAdd<CT1,CT2>`.  That means you can't declare the `operator+()` before the definition of `ExprAdd` though.

Comment: Be explicit in the return type `ExprAdd<CT1, CT2>` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/G4TWGYvaE).

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks for the demo. Although, this won't work on my real application due to the sequence when the operator gets declared

Comment: You have to break the cycle somewhere, maybe adding extra (external) traits.

Comment: If we can do it with additional traits - that will be a great solution.

Comment: Suggestions how this would be achieved?

Comment: Actually, the suggested won't work as updated in the question.

Comment: Why can't you just forward declare `ExprAdd` and use `ExprAdd<CT1,CT2>` as the return type of `operator+`, avoiding the complications of `decltype(auto)`?

Comment: Because `ExprAdd<CT1,CT2>` won't be the return in the example shown above.

Comment: It would be `const ExprAdd<CT1,CT2>` instead. So why can't you declare `ExprAdd` first and then use `inline const ExprAdd<CT1,CT2> operator+( const baseContainer<CT1>&, const baseContainer<CT2>& );` or even `inline auto operator+( const baseContainer<CT1>&, const baseContainer<CT2>& ) -> const ExprAdd<CT1,CT2>;`?

Comment: `ExprAdd<CT1, CT2>` inherits from `baseContainer<ExprAdd<CT1, CT2>>`. you might also uses `baseContainer<ExprAdd<CT1, CT2>>` as return type. I don't see the blocking point from shown code.

Comment: For external type_traits, use `template <typename T1, typename T2> struct result_of_plus;` and use (partial) specialization later to define typedef `type` inside. Then replace `decltype(auto)` by `typename result_of_plus<baseContainer<CT1>, baseContainer<CT2>>::type`.